# Copy Data from a table in one Database to a wordpress database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, wordpress

How do I copy the data from one table in a database into a wordpress database? so the table from my own database is called 'articles' and I have installed WordPress on my local machine and it comes with tables automatically and theres a table called 'wp_posts' which is where im trying to copy the articles too. So I'm trying to move the website I have created other to a wordpress site but I do not want to lose all the already created articles. How would I do this? I have tried this but I get a SQL syntax error.

```
INSERT INTO wp_seetheuniverse.dbo.wp_posts ('wp_title', 'wp_content')
SELECT 'title', 'content' FROM seetheuniverse.dbo.articles;
```

this is the error I get

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
syntax to use near '.wp_posts ('wp_title', 'wp_content') SELECT
'title', 'content' FROM seetheuniver' at line 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

be sure  you have corresponding column (number and type) in INTO and select  clause

```
    INSERT INTO wp_seetheuniverse.dbo.wp_posts (col1, col2, col3)
    SELECT your_col1, your_col, your_col3 
    FROM seetheuniverse.dbo.articles;
```

don't use  single quote around column name eventualy us backtics for composite column name or reserved  words

```
INSERT INTO wp_seetheuniverse.wp_posts (wp_title, wp_content)
SELECT title, content FROM seetheuniverse.articles;
```

and be sure you are using the right database.schema.table reference

```
INSERT INTO dbo.wp_seetheuniverse.wp_posts (wp_title, wp_content)
SELECT title, content FROM dbo.seetheuniverse.articles;
```

Comment: does it matter if one table has more columns than the other?

Comment: yes  .. if one table have more columns then  others  then you cannot use select *  ..but you must select in corresponding order the columns you really need  only,  and matching  for data type too.  SQL can't choose the columns you need  copy and the columns you don't need .. so you must specify  in query

Comment: Im still getting this error, ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.wp_posts (wp_title, wp_content) SELECT title, content FROM seetheuniverse.dbo.a' at line 1

Answer (score 0):

Your table reference has three parts. Typically the parts describe the database, the schema and the table in such a three part identifier, for example in SQL Server. But in MySQL schema and database are synonym, so only two part identifiers are valid. Most likely you copied that `dbo` from some example for SQL Server, I guess.

Another thing is to never enclose column (or any other object) names in single quotes. Single quotes are used to denote string literals. So unless you want a literal string value with the column name, rather than the column's content, don't use single quotes.

Try:

```
INSERT INTO wp_seetheuniverse.wp_posts
            (wp_title,
             wp_content)
            SELECT title,
                   content
                   FROM seetheuniverse.articles;
```